# If a query return empty row i need to get its as zero value,How can check it in Sql?

Tags: sql

```sql
Update TABLE_A
Set  TABLE_A.Form_8 =(Case When TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8' Then  TABLE_B. Invoice_NO End)
From TABLE_A
Inner Join (Select Max(Invoice_NO) as Invoice_NO,Form_Type, Counter_Name From Sales_Master
Group By Counter_Name,Form_Type
) TABLE_B on  TABLE_A.Counter_Name = TABLE_B.Counter_Name and 

TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8'
```

Below Inner Join in the query expected the output as empty,
But actually I want to set Invoice_No as 0

```sql
Select Max(Invoice_NO) as Invoice_NO,Form_Type, Counter_Name 
From Sales_Master
Group By Counter_Name,Form_Type
```

[image]

Comment: Which server are you using ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed looks like SQL Server, based on the image

Comment: I wasn't able to see image at first. It got updated now

Comment: @MarcGravell it's an issue with SQL Server that it doesn't return `0` if nothing found. As `MAX()` function is supposed to be with `int` return type but it doesn't work so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your best bet here is to use a `LEFT OUTER` join instead of an `INNER JOIN`, and use `ISNULL`; the `LEFT OUTER` means that you'll keep the row even when it doesn't match anything, and the `ISNULL` lets you choose a value to use in that scenario; so:

```sql
Update TABLE_A
Set  TABLE_A.Form_8 =(Case When TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8' Then  ISNULL(TABLE_B.Invoice_NO, 0) End)
From TABLE_A
Left Outer Join (Select Max(Invoice_NO) as Invoice_NO,Form_Type, Counter_Name From Sales_Master
Group By Counter_Name,Form_Type
) TABLE_B on  TABLE_A.Counter_Name = TABLE_B.Counter_Name and 

TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8'
```

Comment: I'd recommend use of COALESCE over ISNULL

Comment: @CaiusJard any particular reason in this context, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Marc Gravell.Thank you for the Answer.It Works Fine,Returns  Null So that I Can Check ISNULL

Comment: @CaiusJard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull ISNULL is better in most scenarios, including this one

Answer (score 0):

You could use `case`statment and this will work with many diffrent providers.

Here is how you could do it.

```js
Update TABLE_A
Set  TABLE_A.Form_8 =(Case When TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8' Then 
(case when TABLE_B.Invoice_NO is null then 0 else TABLE_B. Invoice_NO end) End)
From TABLE_A
Inner Join (Select Max(Invoice_NO) as Invoice_NO,Form_Type, Counter_Name From Sales_Master
Group By Counter_Name,Form_Type
) TABLE_B on  TABLE_A.Counter_Name = TABLE_B.Counter_Name and 

TABLE_B.Form_Type ='8'
```

Comment: Why are you using `case` instead of built-in function i.e. `ISNULL`?

Comment: Diffrent providers. so we have one sql instead

Comment: Yeh is that why you wrote `and NVL in Oracle.` but it is preferable to me to use `case` statment anyway. Its a solution that could work its upp to her to choose what to use right :)

Comment: @Alen.Toma..Thank you for the Answer.I have tried it.But its not working.

Comment: Yes i see that, i think your adding the case estatment in the wrong section. there is a group by in the inner join thats why its not working. but adding the case statement in the `Set  TABLE_A.Form_8` should work. I updated it my answer, try it and let me know

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed consider SO as an international audience with many different people looking for answers, not just OP. In SQL particularly, aiming to write answers using standard SQL rather than DB specific SQL does two things; makes the answer more relevant to more people, and improves the cross-db skills of the person answering. Always aim to use standard SQL.. By th way, COALESCE is standard SQL, and more compact than case when for giving nulls a value

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want the maximum invoice number for form type 8.  If so the filtering needs to be *inside* the subquery.

To assign all values, simply use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
update a
    set a.Form_8 = sm.Invoice_NO
from table a left join
     (select Counter_Name, Max(Invoice_NO) as Invoice_NO
      from Sales_Master sm
      where sm.Form_Type ='8'
      group by Counter_Name
     ) sm
     on a.Counter_Name = sm.Counter_Name;
```

Comment: @Gordon.Thank you for the Answer

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ISNULL` in SQL Server .

```
Select ISNULL(Max(Invoice_NO),0) as Invoice_NO,Form_Type, Counter_Name 
From Sales_Master
Group By Counter_Name,Form_Type
```

Comment: @Muhnmmad Waheed  .Thank you for the Answer.I have tried it.But its not working.

Comment: This won't work if there is no row for ISNULL to work on. The OP says there is no row,. the only way to make it work is either to use left join and COALESCE the nul lthat results, or to use UNION SELECT 0 to ensure there is at least one row returned